# VueJS - Composition API - How to properly import and read a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I am having some trouble loading in a local JSON file to read some data. It seems I can get the data to import as I can log it out to the console. If I do console `console.log(rooms.value)` for example I get the following in chrome browser:

[image]

I want to iterate through the data, however if I try a `v-for="room in rooms"` and output `room.id` for example I just get [image]

Please can someone help?

JSON:

```
{
    "rooms":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Master Bedroom",
            "floor": 1,
            "lights": true,
            "blinds": true,
            "climate": true,
            "music": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Living Room",
            "floor": 0,
            "lights": true,
            "blinds": true,
            "climate": true,
            "music": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Vue:

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import roomData from '../../data/db.json'

export default {
    components: {},

    setup(){
        const rooms = ref(roomData)

        console.log(rooms.value)

        return { rooms }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: In your explanation you write: "however if I try a v-for="room in rooms" and output rooms.id"
This might just be a typo in your explanation, but it should be room.id not rooms.id :)

Comment: Sorry it's a typo in my question. My code does actually state room.id, so it must be something else. I've amended the question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can call result of iteration with `room.id` not `rooms.id`, this might just be a typo in your `template` code.

Comment: Hi there, so it's actually a typo in my question. My code does actually state room.id, so it must be something else. Sorry I've amended my question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out - I could only access the array by assigning the constant to `roomData.rooms` (as opposed to just `roomData`). So working code looks like:

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import roomData from '../../data/db.json'

export default {
    components: {},

    setup(){
        const rooms = ref(roomData.rooms)

        console.log(rooms.value)

        return { rooms }
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to import your json you can do this with SFC in vuejs3

```
  <script setup>
    import roomData from '../../data/db.json'
    
    console.log(roomData)
    </script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: effectively !! I modify